# API CSV import creates events that start and end at midnight

Tags: civievent, import

Importing the .csv quoted below to create Events. The snippet further down shows the field mappings. Everything comes across correctly except the time components of Start Date and End Date, which get set to 12:00 AM of the correct date. Once I get these to work, there are another 200+ to import. Anything I should do differently to capture the correct times?

```
Event Type,Start Date,End Date,Title,Default Role,Is Active,Is Public,Share Social
Performance,11/15/2022 07:00,11/15/2022 14:30,BBTB,Attendee,No,No,No
Performance,11/17/2022 07:00,11/17/2022 14:30,BBTS,Attendee,No,No,No
```

Using extension CSV GUI Import to api v1.10, CiviCRM 5.55.1, Drupal 7.91, PHP 7.4.33, MySQL 5.7.40

[image: Field mappings]

Comment: The format i see in the DB is yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 - maybe unlikely but perhaps try with the seconds too

Comment: Appending the seconds (:00) didn't change the end result. Interesting twist to check, though! In other news, I was able to test the import in the Circle Interactive demo (https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/). The result was the same, Start and End times set to midnight.

Comment: sounds like you need to open an issue. only other quick suggestion would be an sql insert built from your csv

Comment: Issue https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/issues/55. Thanks Pete.

Answer (score 2):

Worked around this by following up on @petednz comment and sticking with the default date format. The failing imports used mm/dd/yyyy (1st snippet below). Selecting the default date format (yyyy-mm-dd) and reformatting the .csv accordingly (2nd snippet) parsed the times correctly.

[image: Date Format selection]

[image: Reformatted data and mappings]

Comment: ah good stuff :-)